# How I delete all images from folder or storage in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, domdocument, unlink, domxpath

I have created 'create_post' using **summernote**.  So I can upload text and images in the field. But Now I want to delete my post. I can delete post and image from database and folder but only one image in the post. if I have many images, How can I delete all images?. Here my code so far.

> Image sources $post_id

```
<html>  
........
     <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="http://localhost/public/sample1.jpg"/>
                <p class="title">Sample 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="http://localhost/public/sample2.jpg"/>
                <p class="title">Sample 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.........
</html>
```

> controller.php

```
public function destroy($post_id)
    {
        //
        $post = Post::findOrFail($post_id);
        $image_path = public_path(). '/upload/' . $post->isi;
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML($image_path);//get image form html

        $ext = new DOMXPath($doc);
        /*$srcs = $ext->query('//img/@src');//jikuk data soko tag src img
        foreach ($srcs as $src) {
            $result = array();
            $result['img']= $ext->query('//img/@src', $src)[0]->value;
            $filename[] = basename($result);
            //$results[]=$result;
        }*/
        $src = $ext->evaluate('string(//img/@src)');
        $filename = basename($src);
        $img_path = public_path(). '/upload/'. $filename;//replace with folder path
        libxml_clear_errors();
        unlink($img_path);//delete image from path 

        $post->delete();

        Session::flash('alert-hapus', 'Post berhasil di HAPUS');
        return redirect()->route('metadata');

    }
```

Any help me, please?

Comment: So, your post entity and image entity have one-to-many relation? One post can have many images? Do you set that up in models? You have to use simply `foreach()`, retreive all your image names and delete them in certain directory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I have tried using 'foreach()' but I comment it above because Still error. I use one entity. So When I post text and images, it will be saved in one coloumn table and the images will be saved to directory. @Tarasovych